# How do I set the Title of my application in the Top Toolbar in Nebeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an application in Java created by Netbeans that has a title above the toolbar of:

MyApp 14-cf42d87113e1a2dblahblah

This is not useful to my users. I would like to include a revision number in the title, as that would be more useful than a GUID from Mercurial. That revision number would be under my control.

Modifying the various Bundle.properties files (see below) has no apparent effect.

```
$ grep -r "MyApp {0}" .
./MyApp/branding/src/main/nbm-branding/core/core.jar/org/netbeans/core/startup/Bundle.properties:currentVersion=MyApp {0}
./MyApp/branding/src/main/nbm-branding/modules/org-netbeans-core-windows.jar/org/netbeans/core/windows/view/ui/Bundle.properties:CTL_MainWindow_Title=MyApp {0}
./MyApp/branding/src/main/nbm-branding/modules/org-netbeans-core-windows.jar/org/netbeans/core/windows/view/ui/Bundle.properties:CTL_MainWindow_Title_No_Project=MyApp {0}
```

The {0} implies that somewhere the first parameter in the call is used but I can't figure out what is calling what.

I am using Netbeans IDE 15 and Java 15.

I have wandered through Netbeans properties and configuration without finding the key to changing it. Internet searches have not come up with anything that works either. I also haven't found anything that helps in the Netbeans documents.

Answer (score 0):

From the [NetBeans wiki](https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/DevFaqMainTitle.html):

Inside the ModuleInstaller class for the GUI module:

```
@Override
public void restored() {
  // some other code may go here...
   WindowManager.getDefault().invokeWhenUIReady(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      JFrame mainFrame = (JFrame) WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
      mainFrame.setTitle("Modified main title");
     });
   }
  // some other code may go here...
}
```